# How to dynamically install a particular version of a NPM package based on local Node.js version?

Tags: node.js

I did Google about this but no luck.

Basically, I need a particular version of a NPM package (A) to be installed if the local Node.js version is X, if not then install version B of that NPM package. This needs to be a part of build process, so its all dynamic.

If there was a way to have this config in package.json, then it would have been a straightforward solution for me.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) as your dependency management tool in combination with the [Selective Versions Resolutions](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/blob/master/implemented/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md) feature.

More specifically in your case you'd use it as described in the ["Mapping version specifications"](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/blob/master/implemented/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md#mapping-version-specifications) format, based on that your package.json you would include something like the following, assuming that version X=1.0.3 and version B=2.0.0 in the following example:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "a": "1.0.3"
},
"resolutions": {
  "a@==1.0.3": "a@2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use yarn since this project needs to support older version of Node.js that yarn does not support. This is definitely good to know though. +1

Comment: @RahulDesai in that case take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions, I haven't tested it but could be similar to the Yarn one.

Comment: That seems to need the `npx` command which my older version of Node.js does not support. Plus, I am hoping to do this all with the settings in package.json alone.